# Install lme4 from CRAN on Ubuntu

Tags: r, lme4

I'm having trouble installing the `lme4` package from CRAN on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm running `install.packages("lme4")` on R 3.4.4 and get the following error:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/home/peter/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/nloptr’
ERROR: dependency ‘nloptr’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/peter/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/lme4’
```

Looking more closely, I see these two error lines:

`libtool: link: ERROR: no information for variable 'AR' cru .libs/libutil.a .libs/mt19937ar.o .libs/sobolseq.o .libs/timer.o .libs/stop.o .libs/redblack.o .libs/qsort_r.o .libs/rescale.o`

`checking for ranlib... ERROR: no information for variable 'RANLIB'`

However, both `ar` and `ranlib` commands work on my machine. What may be the cause of the errors?

Comment: transcribing comment from @marco (posted as answer, now-deleted):  "I´m struggling with the same issue. Have you found a way to solve it? When I try to install lme4 package from R, not r studio, it says that the c++ compiler is not working; now I'm trying to guess to which compiler does the error refers."

Comment: have you tried installing binary versions of the packages by following the [Ubuntu instructions on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) ?

Comment: PS https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u has binary packages for R < 3.5 I think; but unless you *need* the earlier version it's probably worth installing a more recent version of R (which you can do easily via the link in the previous comment)

Comment: To my experience, for R 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 22.04, we are missing `nlopt`, which can be fixed with `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev` in terminal. Then it shall compile.

Answer (score 20):

You just need to install the older version of nloptr package.

For example:

```
packageurl<-"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nloptr/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz"

install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I guess you are using R 3.X. Such error is caused by package update for supporting R 4.0.

Comment: This worked for me

```packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nloptr/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz"; 
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source");```

Comment: @mmoisse Thank you! I was dealing with this bug on my work machine that uses R 3.5.1 and your comment saved me :)