# Unable to install ggpubr

Tags: r, installation, ggpubr

I am attempting to download the package `ggpubr`. My R studio version is 3.5.2. I've been trying to install `ggpubr` library via:

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
```

and

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr)
```

But when I do that, I get this error:

````
    clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
    make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘conquer’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/conquer```
    
#Followed by:
    
    ../libtool: line 1099: ERROR:: command not found
    make[2]: *** [libutil.la] Error 127
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/nloptr’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependency ‘conquer’ is not available for package ‘quantreg’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/quantreg’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependency ‘nloptr’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/lme4’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’ are not available for package ‘car’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/car’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘rstatix’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rstatix’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependency ‘rstatix’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ggpubr’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status
````

I'm  not sure what to do. I've tried independently installing `conquer`, and a handful of other things that didn't help...

I tried simply using `install.package("ggpubr")`, and I also tried `if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr")`.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependencies is only available for `R >= 4` so you need to manually install an older version of `nloptr`.

The solution is to manually install an older version of the dependency (nloptr):

```
packageurl<-"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nloptr/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz"
```

Then:

```
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Source: [Install lme4 from CRAN on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900525/install-lme4-from-cran-on-ubuntu)